# systemd looking for update-rc.d when I try to enable redis service in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, logs, services, redis

I was trying to install **redis** from source in Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.
I did followed everything exactly from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.

Only difference was that my *logfile* path was `/redis/logs/redis-server.log` instead of `/var/log/redis.log` in **redis.conf** file.

It worked perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04 but in Ubuntu 14.04, while enabling `redis.service` through command `sudo systemctl enable redis`, systemd started searching for *init* file and and tried to enable through `update-rc.d` rather than usual method i.e. creating a soft link of `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` directory. Of course, it couldn't because there was no *init* file for redis.

Later, I changed the path of *logfile* to `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log` in Ubuntu 14 only and it fixed the problem. My question is why this happened? Is there some dependency of *systemd* on *logfile* location? What changed in Ubuntu 16?